# drag and drop winform controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to drag and drop a control (label for example) in a winform application. I saw some examples on dragging and dropping text, but this is not what I want. I want to enable the user to move a control around. Can anyone direct me to some resources or examples? Thanks.

Comment: do you just want to relocate the controls or do you need the "drop"-features where the information is transfered?

Comment: [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/178587/Draggable-WinForms-Controls?display=Print) is useful simple extension.

Comment: See also my arcticle on The Code Project: [www.codeproject.com/Articles/36412/Drag-and-Drop-ListBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36412/Drag-and-Drop-ListBox). But just moving a Label araound on a form is not drag-and-drop!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should look at examples on how to make draggable controls.

There are some answers here in SO as well.

See this [Move controls when Drag and drop on panel in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439061/move-controls-when-drag-and-drop-on-panel-in-c)

this is a complete example on how to host the Form Designer:

[Tailor Your Application by Building a Custom Forms Designer with .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc163871.aspx)

I did something similar in Delphi long time ago, will search the source code, convert it into .NET C# and make a wiki page on that matter, as it is becoming such popular question recently :)

Comment: Davide Piras would be nice if you can show how hosting forms designer works better than adding code to allow control movement and to save the new positions for later form loading 
BTW for original link for hosting designer is obsolete. a possible link is https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rprabhu/2004/06/15/designer-hosting-in-whidbey/?replytocom=5005#respond

but the replacement is not very useful as it does not show to to emit C# code or what can be done with the designer surface. there is still a lot implementation details left out.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i understand, where you wish to drop a control is called a container, infact any control can act as a container. So first that container, you need to enable the drop property as well as the drag property of the controls which you need to drag.

Then write events (Candrag, candrop, controladded, etc.) for each control where in which, some logic to hold the objects and display them as you may want.

Say, ill take an example where in which, you wish to drag imagetext from combombox into a picturebox and then make the picturebox analyze the text and fine related file name in a directory and load that image into its if its present.

So here, when you start dragging the text from combombox, you have to write some logic in event candrag. Then once you drop, you have to write logic to understand what kinda object was added and get the text related to it (kinda deciphering) in the control where you drop other control.

Sorry, i have no code to give you now, but i hope you got the idea how its done. May be this article can help you? http://vicky4147.wordpress.com/2007/02/04/a-simple-drag-drop-in-winforms/

Comment: In fact you can but you would not really drop controls in a button or checkbox. only form or panels and few others are good containers.

Comment: Yep true, may be we dont coz there is no use dragging n dropping into textbox right. After all textbox can just display the text (if present) in the dropped control. So no use :).

Answer (score 0):

```
    bool draging = false;
    int curPosX, curPosY;
    private void label2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        draging = true;
        curPosX = Cursor.Position.X;
        curPosY = Cursor.Position.Y;
    }
    private void label2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (draging)
        {
            label2.Left += Cursor.Position.X - curPosX;
            curPosX = Cursor.Position.X;
            label2.Top += Cursor.Position.Y - curPosY;
            curPosY = Cursor.Position.Y;
        }
    }
    private void label2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        draging = false;
    }
```