# DragDrop between controls

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, controls, containers

I have a problem with DragDrop.

```
    private void Form0_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox panel1 = new PictureBox();
        PictureBox panel2 = new PictureBox();

        mainPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(mainPanel);

        panel1.Location = new Point(10, 10);
        panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 300);
        panel1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

        Button b2 = new Button();
        b2.Location = new Point(10, 10);
        panel2.Controls.Add(b2);
        panel2.Location = new Point(10, 10);
        panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
        panel2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

        foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
        {
            c.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseDown);
            c.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseMove);
            c.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseUp);
            c.AllowDrop = true;
        }
        panel1.AllowDrop = true;

        panel1.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(container_DragEnter);
        panel1.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(container_DragDrop);
        panel1.DragOver += new DragEventHandler(container_DragOver);

        foreach (Control c in panel2.Controls)
        {
            c.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseDown);
            c.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseMove);
            c.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseUp);
            c.AllowDrop = true;
        }
        panel2.AllowDrop = true;

        panel2.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(container_DragEnter);
        panel2.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(container_DragDrop);
        panel2.DragOver += new DragEventHandler(container_DragOver);

        mainPanel.Controls.Add(panel1);
        mainPanel.Controls.Add(panel2);
        mainPanel.Controls.Add(pb);
    }

    private void control_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Control c = sender as Control;
        isDragging = true;
        clickOffsetX = e.X;
        clickOffsetY = e.Y;
    }

    private void control_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Control c = sender as Control;
        if (isDragging == true)
        {
            c.Left = e.X + c.Left - clickOffsetX;
            c.Top = e.Y + c.Top - clickOffsetY;
            if (c.Location.X + clickOffsetX > c.Parent.Width ||
                c.Location.Y + clickOffsetY > c.Parent.Height ||
                c.Location.X + clickOffsetX < 0 ||
                c.Location.Y + clickOffsetY < 0)

                c.DoDragDrop(c, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }

    private void control_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isDragging = false;
    }

    void container_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    private void container_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        //e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;

        //if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Bitmap)))
        //{
        //    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        //}
    }

    private void container_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Control c = e.Data.GetData(e.Data.GetFormats()[0]) as Control;
        PictureBox p = sender as PictureBox;
        mycontrol = c;
        isDragging = false;
        if (c != null)
        {
            c.Location = p.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            p.Controls.Add(c);
        }
    }
```

This is a working example. But I can't do drop Controls from parent to child control. What is a magic? How to drop control to another control (from panel1 to panel2 in my example).

Comment: @justAuser: what u actally wants to do? on which conrol you want drop the other control? can u please explian the scenario..

Comment: @ Smack: Question is how do I can drop child to another Child of same parent?

Comment: You need to reparent the controls. Change the `Parent` property. I don't know what answer you're looking for, the question still hasn't gotten any clearer. It's just a giant wall of [working] code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some answers here in SO, which may help you:

See this [Move controls when Drag and drop on panel in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439061/move-controls-when-drag-and-drop-on-panel-in-c-sharp)

this is a complete example on how to host the Form Designer:

[Tailor Your Application by Building a Custom Forms Designer with .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc163871.aspx)

Check this one also for simple lable drag drop:
[Basic drag and drop in WinForms](http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2007/07/07/basic-drag-and-drop-in-winforms/)

Comment: I've seen these examples before. It is fine. But, there are no solutions that would help in my case. Question is how do I can move child to another Child of same parent?

Comment: send the control id which you are dragging and remove that from parent and add to that subpanel on which you are dropping.. you can find control with id in parent..