# Treeview drag and drop without destination node

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, treeview

I have two `TreeView` which are in seperate forms.

- `treeView1`
- `treeView2`

I  implemented a `Drag and Drop` functionality so that I can drag from on tree to another and it works fine with the code I found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307968) where I have to handle 3 events.

The thing is the setup of my windows looks like this :

[image]

As you can see, `Window2` hides my `Window1` and **it's on purpose and needs to stay like this**. The problem is my `Drag and Drop` is from `Window2` to `Window1` so I can't specify a destination node. Is there a way to simply drop into a `TreeView` without any destination node and say create a parent node next to the other ones ?

---

Links die examples don't :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.treeView1.ItemDrag += new System.Windows.Forms.ItemDragEventHandler(this.treeView_ItemDrag);
    this.treeView2.ItemDrag += new System.Windows.Forms.ItemDragEventHandler(this.treeView_ItemDrag);
    this.treeView1.DragEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.treeView_DragEnter);
    this.treeView2.DragEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.treeView_DragEnter);
    this.treeView1.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.treeView_DragDrop);
    this.treeView2.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.treeView_DragDrop);   
}

private void treeView_ItemDrag(object sender,
        System.Windows.Forms.ItemDragEventArgs e)
{
    DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Move);
}

private void treeView_DragEnter(object sender,
        System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

private void treeView_DragDrop(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode NewNode;

    if(e.Data.GetDataPresent("System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode", false))
    {
        Point pt = ((TreeView)sender).PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        TreeNode DestinationNode = ((TreeView)sender).GetNodeAt(pt);
            NewNode = (TreeNode)e.Data.GetData("System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode");
        if(DestinationNode.TreeView != NewNode.TreeView)
        {     
            DestinationNode.Nodes.Add((TreeNode) NewNode.Clone());
            DestinationNode.Expand();
            //Remove Original Node
            NewNode.Remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can't see the destination treeview, how can you call it a drop? Instead use a right-click menu maybe?

Comment: Drop it on Window 1, then get it to deal with TreeView1. Is this for the world's most unintuitive interface competition?

Comment: @Bolu i'm sorry my mistake. The tree view is visible at the bottom. the only thing i can't see are the tree nodes in treeview1 that's why I can't choose a destination node.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Open an Explorer folder with pictures in it with your desktop barely visible at the bottom. Now drag a picture from the folder to the desktop. Is Windows the most unintuitive interface ?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson also the Window does not have a ItemDrag event

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Most unintuitive? Not the place for that debate.The desktop is the windows / control you are dropping the file on. Drag and drop is from one visible control to another. I wouldn't look at your app and think I could do that, that's why it's unintuitive. Have a look at this, just cheat and put all your controls in a panel. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439061/move-controls-when-drag-and-drop-on-panel-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `treeview_dragdrop` of both `forms` to the following:

```
   private void treeView_DragDrop(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode NewNode;

        if(e.Data.GetDataPresent("System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode", false))
        {
            NewNode = (TreeNode)e.Data.GetData("System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode");
            if (!(sender as TreeView).Nodes.Contains(NewNode))//Edit: add this if you don't want to add the same one again.
            {    
                 (sender as TreeView).Nodes.Add((TreeNode) NewNode.Clone());                 
                 NewNode.Remove(); //Edit: add this if you want to remove original one.
            } 
        }
    }
```