# Moving textboxes within a panel with drag and drop and reorganising them while moving

Tags: c#, winforms

i have been searching but no answers yet found to my problem been. If there is already an answer i am sorry i didn't find it. Please point it to me, thanks.

I have a panel (size: 350*60) within a form. In this panel i have got 5 textbox (size each: 70*60). I want to be able to perform a drag and drop operation (or mouseEvents) of this elements within this panel (if the cursor go out this panel, the textbox stays on the panel) but horizontally only. If i take textbox 1 and i want to leave it in the 3rd position, textbox2 and 3 will move one position left. If i want to move number 5 to 2nd position, textbox2,3,4 will move one position right.

I want to do something similar like the bar at the bottom of Windows, where you can take controls and move them around this bar.

If anyone can help me, i will continue to found my answer if i find it i will post it here.

I am using winform, visual studio, c# to make a .dll for a dynamic nav controlAddIn.

Thanks to all that knows how to help and to the others as well.

Good day

I am posting the code, can anyone understanding it, can help me:

## region DRAG AND DROP

```
    // Tengo que probar lo escrito en la libreta, con posInicial, posCruce, areaPermitida, isDragging, sueltaBoton
    TextBox tbInitial = new TextBox();//tb ou je rentre
    TextBox tbFinal = new TextBox();//tb ou je laisse
    Color colorPrimaire = new Color();//pour changer la couleur de rentrage au textbox
    Boolean _mouseDown = false; //si c'est appuyé
    Point _mouseDownPos; // position a l'appuillage du mouse
    Point tbPosInitial, tbPosFinal;// position a l'appuillage et au laissage des tb
    Rectangle tbRectInitial, tbRectFinal; // rectangle des tb initial et final
    // Commence le drag and drop en lui passant le control est proprietées et les types d'effect
    private void tb_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            colorPrimaire = tb.BackColor;
            tbInitial = (sender as TextBox);
            tbPosInitial = tbInitial.Location;
            _mouseDown = true;
            _mouseDownPos = e.Location;
            tbInitial.BringToFront();
            tbRectInitial = tbInitial.DisplayRectangle;
            tbInitial.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(tbInitial_DragEnter);
        }
    }

    private void tbInitial_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_mouseDown)//pour pouvoir bouger horizontalement
        {
            Point posPremiere = new Point(70, 0);
            Point posUltime = new Point(nRoles * 70, 0);
            int deltaX = e.X - _mouseDownPos.X;
            int deltaY = e.Y - _mouseDownPos.Y;

            tbInitial.Location = new Point(tb.Left + deltaX, tb.Top /* + deltaY */);
            tbInitial.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
            tbFinal = (sender as TextBox);
            tbPosFinal = tbFinal.Location;
            tbRectFinal = tbFinal.DisplayRectangle;

            int numRolInicial = tbPosInitial.X / 70;
            int numRolFinal = tbPosFinal.X / 70;
            //Pour commencer le drag                
            tbInitial.DoDragDrop(tbInitial, DragDropEffects.Move);
            //Pour faire bouger les textbox, je dois lui dire que tout les tb from tbInitial jusqu'a tbFinal doivent bouger + ou - une position
            tbInitial.AllowDrop = true;
            //Pour gerer le drop et le leave et le enter sur le tbFinal
            tbFinal.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(tbFinal_DragEnter);
            tbFinal.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(tbFinal_DragDrop);
            tbFinal.DragLeave += new EventHandler(tbFinal_DragLeave);
            //Pour ne pas pouvoir aller en dehors les limites
            if (tbPosInitial.X < posPremiere.X)
            {
                tbPosFinal = posPremiere;
            }

            if (tbPosInitial.X > posUltime.X)
            {
                tbPosFinal = posUltime;
            }
        }
    }

    private void tbFinal_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    private void tbFinal_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        _mouseDown = false;
        MessageBox.Show("TbInitial location:" + tbPosInitial.ToString());//me da la posicion del raton en el textbox
        MessageBox.Show("TbFinal location:" + tbPosFinal.ToString());//me da la posicion final del textbox

        EventControlAddin(3, tbInitial.Name.PadRight(10) + ";" + (string)tbFinal.Name);

        if (colorPrimaire == Color.Bisque)
        {
            tb.BackColor = Color.Bisque;
        }
        else
        {
            tb.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        }

    }

    private void tbFinal_DragLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Je dois recommencer tous.
        tb = tbFinal;
        tb.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(tb_MouseDown);
    }

    private void tb_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_mouseDown)//pour pouvoir bouger horizontalement
        {
            Point posPremiere = new Point(70, 0);
            Point posUltime = new Point(MainPanel.Controls.Count * 70, 0);
            int deltaX = e.X - _mouseDownPos.X;
            int deltaY = e.Y - _mouseDownPos.Y;

            tbInitial.Location = new Point(tb.Left + deltaX, tb.Top /* + deltaY */);
            tbInitial.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
            tbFinal = (sender as TextBox);
            tbPosFinal = tbFinal.Location;
            tbRectFinal = tbFinal.DisplayRectangle;

            int numRolInicial = tbPosInitial.X / 70;
            int numRolFinal = tbPosFinal.X / 70;
            //Pour faire bouger les textbox, je dois lui dire que tout les tb from tbInitial jusqu'a tbFinal doivent bouger + ou - une position                

            //Pour ne pas pouvoir aller en dehors les limites
            if (tbInitial.Location.X < posPremiere.X)
            {
                tbPosFinal = posPremiere;
            }

            if (tbInitial.Location.X > posUltime.X)
            {
                tbPosFinal = posUltime;
            }
        }
    }


    private void tb_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _mouseDown = false;
        MessageBox.Show("TbInitial location:" + tbPosInitial.ToString());//me da la posicion del raton en el textbox
        MessageBox.Show("TbFinal location:" + tbPosFinal.ToString());//me da la posicion final del textbox

        EventControlAddin(3, tbInitial.Name.PadRight(10) + ";" + (string)tbFinal.Name);

        if (colorPrimaire == Color.Bisque)
        {
            tb.BackColor = Color.Bisque;
        }
        else
        {
            tb.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        }
    }
```

## endregion

Comment: This Question/Answer should give you most all the information you need to get going: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439061/move-controls-when-drag-and-drop-on-panel-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: Hi John Arlen, I am trying to do with the page you point it at me but still a little lost. I posted my code if anyone is willing to put a little light into the kaos. Thanks

Comment: I just changed my code, i think i need to know which textboxes are crossed by the textbox that i am holding with the mouse, but no luck yet trying to do that.